# Where are My Links stored?

Tags: user-profile, my-site

Where does SharePoint store My Links?  For example, a list on a users My Site, the User Profile database, etc...

I'm looking at this feature that was in SharePoint 2007:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-server-help/add-and-manage-the-links-on-your-my-site-HA010168638.aspx

But seems to have been hidden/deprecated in SharePoint 2010/2013 but still available:

http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.ca/2013/04/tips-for-add-to-my-links-function-on.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MyLinks control is hidden in SharePoint 2010, but as you point out still present in both 2010 and 2013. The links are part of the User Profile. So they are in the User Profile Database. You can access them via the QuickLinksManager and the User Profile Property "QuickLinks".

I should point out that the preferred technique in 2010 and 2013 is to use Tags rather than quick Links and there is a feature "Create Tag from Link" to assist in this transition.

```
#QuickLinks Management
$context = Get-SPServiceContext -Site http://mysite
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

$profile = $upm.GetUserProfile("dht\ruby")
#Get the QuickLinks Manager
$qlm = $profile.QuickLinks
#List them
$qlm.GetItems() | fl
```

Comment: Is there any equivalent in CSOM, JSOM, or the REST API?

Are you aware of any articles that show how Tags can be used to replace My Links?

Comment: My Links are not part of REST or any other API as far as I know. There is a link on the my links page that converts the link to a tag and then you can use REST or SCOM to get the Tags for a user through SocialDataService.GetTagsOfUser

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott where is this "Create tag from link" feature that you speak of? Couldn't find it anywhere. The documentation about this is also abysmal.

Comment: On the personal site/_layouts/15/MyQuickLinks.aspx page there is a menu bar that includes "Create Tag from Link".

Answer (score 0):

even-though the My Links feature is obsolete in SharePoint 2013/2016, there is still a client-side equivalent to query the My Links data by using the older

> *.../_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx*

and use the **GetUserLinks** method to get the My Links for each user.